# Seperate gpu tensorlfow scripts running on seperate gpu's

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu, tensorflow2.0

I have recently purchased a second gpu with the thought that I could take advantage of tensorflow-gpu to run some tensorflow script on one gpu and then continue to run other gpu intensive programs on the other.

I was successful in running the tensorflow script on the gpu alone, but when I run another tensorflow script on another gpu I recieve this:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: Blas GEMM launch failed : a.shape=(15, 1024), b.shape=(1024, 1024), m=15, n=1024, k=1024 [Op:MatMul]
```

And when I run another graphicly intense program this throws:

```
2020-07-10 13:41:42.010777: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_event.cc:29] Error polling for event status: failed to query event: CUDA_ERROR_LAUNCH_FAILED: unspecified launch failure
2020-07-10 13:41:42.021608: F tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_event_mgr.cc:273] Unexpected Event status: 1
```

This error
What is going on? Is my fantasy purely fictitious?

EDIT:
It seems that when a gpu intensive program is currently running (i.e. another tensorflow script or a video game or something) the first error occurs. However, if the gpu script is up and running and then a video game or other gpu intensive program lauches, the script slows down and evenutally throws the second error.

Answer (score 1):

```
os.environ["CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER"]="PCI_BUS_ID"
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="0" #select 0 for first GPU or 1 for second
```

Put this script at the very top of any python file to manually assign a GPU.

Comment: I guess I was assuming that `with tf.device()` would assign the gpu, but I will try this.

Comment: Still throws the first error mentioned in the question, when other gpu intensive programs are running.